# Android :Recover files from folder res

Tags: android, android-resources

I accidentally deleted the folder RES from my project .How can I recover it  (strings,  drawable, layout ...)? I look that the files are in R class, but how can I recover them?

Comment: Only the file names are in R.class. Do you have a compiled APK?

Comment: Restore them from your backup of your development machine, or from your version control system.

Comment: Yes I have the apk file!

Comment: Just open it with a Zip Extractor

Comment: Zip extractor? How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have your app managed on Git, SVN. Pull from there.

Answer (score 0):

If not late then go to your 'recycle bin' on your desktop and click it to open.See for the 'res' folder,then right click on it and select 'Restore'. This method will work only if you are a bit lucky!!